# How to generate a whirlpool type pattern using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, loops

I want to create a whirlpool pattern using numpy, but not very sure about the approach.

The Whirpool starts from 0 at the center of an array. Every layer of whirlpool is incremented by 1. The last layer of whirlpool can have any number but only between 1 to 10.
Below image might help for understanding:-

[image]

I want to create a function that generates such whirpool patterns given the digits to be used in last layer. The last layer of whirpool should only allow numbers between 1 to 10 (inclusive). This should not be harcoding.

Comment: I am a little bit confused by your drawing as I it traces a spiral, but I dont see any "spiralness" in the problem. Would it be more correct to call it "level rings" or "onion" (as @TimH says) instead whirpool? Also, would for example `getRings(3)` output your first image?

Answer (score 5):

Very short and concise:

```
def whirlpool(n):
    center = np.abs(np.arange(-n, n + 1))
    return np.maximum.outer(center, center)
```

Comment: I envy elegant solutions like these :) Great job recognizing that this could be done with `np.maximum.outer`!

Comment: How does `np.maximum.outer` work in this context?

Comment: The relevant documentation is here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html, but also have a look at the simpler `np.outer` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html#numpy.outer to get an idea for how the `outer` functionality works. In short, `np.ufunc.outer` calculates the `ufunc` (here `maximum`) of every pair of elements between the two inputs. For two 1D array inputs, the results are nicely laid out in a gridlike manner such as the one requested by OP.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take the liberty of calling this an onion instead of a whirlpool since this matrix has concentric layers instead of a spiral structure.

```py
import numpy as np

def makeOnion(final_layer_num):
    dim = 2 * final_layer_num + 1
    matrix = []
    for row_num in range(dim):
        row = []
        for col_num in range(dim):
            row_centrality = abs(row_num - final_layer_num)
            col_centrality = abs(col_num - final_layer_num)
            row.append(max(row_centrality, col_centrality))
        matrix.append(row)
    return np.array(matrix)
```

If you calculate the "distance" of a row (or column) from the center, it will help with this problem, hence `row_centrality` and `col_centrality`. I just made those terms up though, maybe there are better ones. Whatever the case, the max between row & column centrality for a given entry in the matrix is equal to the layer that it is in.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this function, where `n` is the digit in the outer layer:

```
import numpy as np

def whirlpool(n):
    m = n*2+1
    arr = np.full((m, m), n)
    for l in range(1, n+1):
        arr[l:m-l, l:m-l] = np.full((m-l*2, m-l*2), n-l)
    return arr
        
whirlpool(3)
```

Out:

```
array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I simply create a full 2D array initialized with the maximum value (the outermost layer is "done" from the beginning), then decrement every lower layer by using a loop. This way requires allocating memory only once.

I made two functions where one takes the numer of layers as input and the other takes the maximum value as input. As you can see, converting between them is quite simple:

```py
import numpy as np

def createOnionFromNumberOfLayers(layers: int):
    dim = layers * 2 - 1
    onion = np.full((dim, dim), layers - 1)
    for i in range(1, layers):
        slice_ = slice(i, dim - i)
        onion[slice_, slice_] -= 1
    return onion

def createOnionFromMaxValue(maxval: int):
    return createOnionFromNumberOfLayers(maxval+1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    onion = createOnionFromNumberOfLayers(3)
    print('Given number of layers:\n', onion, '\n')
    onion = createOnionFromMaxValue(4)
    print('Given max value:\n',onion)
```

Output:

```
Given number of layers:
 [[2 2 2 2 2]
  [2 1 1 1 2]
  [2 1 0 1 2]
  [2 1 1 1 2]
  [2 2 2 2 2]]

Given max value:
 [[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
  [4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4]
  [4 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 4]
  [4 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 4]
  [4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4]
  [4 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 4]
  [4 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 4]
  [4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4]
  [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]]
```